CollectionView has worse performance on Windows than on Android
I have a MAUI application which uses a CollectionView. I run it on Windows and on Android. The performance on Android is perfect. Everything works fine and smooth. I have 105 Elements in the CollectionView. When I run on Windows, the page needs way more time to load.
I already use ObservableRangeCollection and tried a fixed width which didn't really improve the performance.
View:
<RefreshView IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}" Command="{Binding LoadPasswordsCommand}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" >
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding PasswordItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPassword}" SelectionMode="Single">
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="3" VerticalItemSpacing="5" HorizontalItemSpacing="5" />
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:PasswordItem">
                <Border HeightRequest="100" Style="{StaticResource CollectionElementDesktop}" CompressedLayout.IsHeadless="true">
                    <VerticalStackLayout CompressedLayout.IsHeadless="true">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Title, Mode=OneTime}" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" FontSize="20"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Username, Mode=OneTime}" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Mail, Mode=OneTime}" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"/>
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</RefreshView>

Style.xaml:
<Style x:Key="CollectionElementDesktop" TargetType="Border">
    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="StrokeShape" Value="RoundRectangle 20,20,20,20"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="Border">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10"/>
    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource Primary}"/>
    <Setter Property="StrokeShape" Value="RoundRectangle 25,25,25,25"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="CenterAndExpand"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="CenterAndExpand"/>
    <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
        <VisualStateGroupList>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState Name="Normal">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState Name="Selected">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateGroupList>
    </Setter>
</Style>

ViewModel:
public RangeObservableCollection<PasswordItem> PasswordItems { get; set; } = [];
    
//...
    
private async Task OnLoadPasswordsClicked()
{
    try
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        var tempList = await App.Database.GetPasswortItemsAsync();
        
        foreach (var p in tempList)
        {
            p.Username = String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Username) ? "Kein Benutzername" : p.Username;
            p.Mail = String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Mail) ? "Keine Email" : p.Mail;
        }
        
        originalPasswordItems = [.. tempList];
        OnChangeOrderTypeClicked();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Exceptions.ThrowExceptionItem(5000, ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        IsBusy = false;
    }
}

I think the main problem is that the display of a Windows machine is bigger and more items can be load6, which needs more time. But I don't now how to solve it. So maybe someone already faced the same problem and can help.

Id start with setting fixed height to the collection view, and building a release version.
